# How to get variable from function.php to loop file

Tags: variables

i had code in function.php file :

```
$selective = new WP_Query($args_selective);

get_template_part( $loopFile );
```

i cant get $seletive in my loop file.
Help me pls. Thanks for any answer !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is a global:

```
global $selective;
$selective = new WP_Query( $args_selective );
```

And then in your template part:

```
global $selective;

// Away we go!
```